# Unable to push array from Node/Express to EJS template

Tags: arrays, node.js, express, ejs

I am unable to push an array from server side express to my EJS template without losing all of it's data types.  I am trying to use Google Charts to display some data.  It requires an array formatted like so,

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work',     11],
    ['Eat',      2],
    ['Commute',  2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep',    7]
     ]);
```

On the server, I have the following code to format my data this way, then I attempt to send that array to my EJS template.

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res){
    Poll.findById(req.params.id, function(err, poll){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.redirect('back')
        } else {
            var optionData = [...poll.options];
            console.log(optionData);
            var optionArray = []
            optionData.forEach(function(option){
                optionArray.push([option.text, option.count]);
            })
            console.log(optionArray);
            res.render('../views/polls/show', {poll: poll, optionArray: optionArray})
        }
    })
})
```

The console.log statements show the following result in the server terminal.

```
server started
[ { count: 2, _id: 5b5d1d93e5a57807b97c6f6e, text: 'lets goo1' },
  { count: 0, _id: 5b5d1d93e5a57807b97c6f6d, text: 'here we go2' },
  { count: 2, _id: 5b5d1d93e5a57807b97c6f6c, text: 'nice nice 3' } ]
[ [ 'lets goo1', 2 ],
  [ 'here we go2', 0 ],
  [ 'nice nice 3', 2 ] ]
```

However, when I try to use my optionArray in EJS, the source code converts it to the following:

```
console.log(<%=optionArray%>)
ends up looking like this in the browsers source code
console.log(lets goo1,2,here we go2,0,nice nice 3,2)
```

Anyone know how to preserve the arrays structure when passing it from node/express to EJS?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <% for(var i=0; i<optionsArray.length; i++) { %>
        <li>
            <%= console.log(optionsArray[i]) %>
        </li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

Try something like this within your ejs template,its a for loop iterating over your optionsArray and same array is accessed indexed